# ActionScript 3.0 TransformGestureEvent and MouseEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, gesture, touch-event, pan

I'm trying to use GESTURE_PAN to move a MC and also use MOUSE_CLICK to go to another frame.
Many people are saying GESTURE_PAN and MOUSE_CLICK work together BUT THEY WON'T ON MY iPhone.
I've read many Q&A on the web and of course on stackoverflow.

```
stop();

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, onPan);
table.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoBox);

function onPan(event: TransformGestureEvent): void
{
    table.x += event.offsetX;
    table.y += event.offsetY;
    if (table.x > (table.width / 2))
    {
        table.x = table.width / 2;
    }
    if (table.x < stage.stageWidth - (table.width / 2))
    {
        table.x = stage.stageWidth - (table.width / 2)
    }
    if (table.y > (table.height / 2))
    {
        table.y = table.height / 2;
    }
    if (table.y < stage.stageHeight - (table.height / 2))
    {
        table.y = stage.stageHeight - (table.height / 2)
    }
}
function gotoBox(e: MouseEvent)
{
    trace("mouse")
}
```

The thing is when i test it on Flash Pro CC Simulator everything works good but not on my iDevice.

Help, I'm running out of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a special settings [mapTouchToMouse](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#mapTouchToMouse) flag to change `MouseEvent` dispatching behavior on device, by default it's set to `true` so you have mouse events in addition to touch events.

But that's mostly done for backward compatibility with desktop/browser apps and has certain performance overhead on mobile devices, so bast practice is to set that flag to `false` and use some mouse/touch events abstraction like [Starling](https://github.com/Gamua/Starling-Framework/tree/master/starling/src/starling/events) touch system or [Gestouch](https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch)

So check if you changed that mapping to `false` somewhere, that's the most probable reason why you don't have mouse events.